# Can I perform a query on an existing Artifactory access token to learn how it was created?

Tags: artifactory, access-token, jfrog-cli

I realize that I cannot retrieve the actual Artifactory access token after the initial creation--either I save it or it is lost.

However, I'm hoping I can still learn other details about the access token at a later date.  Two pieces of information, in particular, would be very valuable:

1. Is the access token an 'admin' token?
2. What permission group(s) did I associate with the token when I created it.

I've looked through the docs and so far have not been able to find how to retrieve any information about an existing access token.  The Artifactory UI shows the date it was created and the user associated with the token and something called a *token ID*.

I'd love to be able to do a query using the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with such API unfortunately.

The jfrog-client-go library (a dependency of JFrog CLI) however does [have the logic](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-client-go/blob/a907eac21179974166df8f1a7f0fe5a6156d005e/auth/authutils.go#L13) of extracting this information from a token. The JFrog CLI uses it in several ways but does not expose a dedicated command.

You can either use this library in your own script to extract this info, or [raise a feature request](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues) for the JFrog CLI to support it.